# SAS Code to examine another SAS program

Tags: sas

I have a bit of a problem trying to code up what I want to do in SAS and I was hoping to get some advice from someone. I was wondering if it is possible to write code that will examine another piece of existing SAS code and bring up a list of the required input datasets and variables. I am wanting to invoke other SAS code in an automated process using the %include function and a prompt for the user to define the exact name/ location of the code as this will be different every time. But before this I want to somehow check this code, rename an existing dataset to be the input dataset and check that I have all the required variables before running the %include.

I was hoping someone might be able to tell me if this is at all possible and if so what function I would use. I am using EG 5.1 if that makes any difference.

Thanks for your help.

Steph.

P.S. Thanks for your help guys. Sorry if this question is outside the scope of this site, I thought there might be a simple function to achieve this, similar to %include. Also, I have never posted on this site before so apologies if I did stuff wrong.

Comment: This is definitely possible with SAS; however, the format of this question isn't quite the best. Try resubmitting with initial attempts and asking questions about specific functions/needs you may have and you will have better answers.

Comment: Agree about re-wording.  Also suggest you check out stored processes.  They allow you to create, for example, some reporting code which has a few parameters, and will create prompts that allow users to pick values for the parameters (dataset names, variable names, whatever).

Comment: I would look more into macros, but question isn't clear enough. If you don't have a SAS server ignore the stored process part.

Comment: @Bruno Franco Please stop making edits that add emphasis to random words in people's posts: this is vandalism. Until now you are just getting away with it by chance, since the edit reviewers are so sloppy... Eventually you'll get an automatic edit ban if you keep doing this.

Comment: Agree @Reese, my first thought was macros too.  But since she wants a prompt interface, thought stored processes.  (No %WINDOW statement with EG for old-style user input) With EG, you can also just have a program that has associated prompts.

Comment: Hi, sorry if I haven't been clear, I haven't posted before. I haven't got any previous attempts because I don't know how to code what I want to do. Basically, as a simple example if programe A is as follows:

Comment: data output; set input; new_var = input_var*100; run; Then I want to write a separate program that will tell me that the required input dataset is called input, the output dataset is called output and the only input variable is input_var. That way I can ensure that the required dataset is present before I run program A. I hope this explains it a bit better.

Comment: Instead of 'backtracing' the code to determine the datasets it uses, take the user-input and simply check that that dataset exists.

Comment: @StephDP  First off, clarify the question by editing it not in comments - comments are ephemeral.  Second off, I think this is more complex than you can really ask as a SO question.  You would need to write a text-parsing program to accomplish this, which isn't necessarily hard but is well outside the scope of what's okay to ask about here.  What you should do is start writing that text parsing program, and if you have specific questions about it, come back.

Comment: This question may violate SO rules so consider posting to communities.sas.com, with some more detail though, for example what would program A do?